# Replacing the deprecated taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();

Tags: android

I am following an android tutorial and I have been stuck on the deprecated method. I am unable to get the download url to enable me show the image in an ImageView

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            StorageReference ref = FirebaseUtil.mStorageRef.child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
            ref.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    String url = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                    String pictureName = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getPath();
                    deal.setImageUrl(url);
```

How can I modify the line `"String url = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();"` so that I can be able to get the download link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDownloadUrl()` is deprecated so you need to use Task and check `isComplete()` like below to see if it is completed

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        StorageReference ref = FirebaseUtil.mStorageRef.child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
        ref.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    Task<Uri> uri = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                    while(!uri.isComplete());
                    Uri url = uri.getResult();

                    Log.i(TAG, url.toString());
                    deal.setImageUrl(url.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you. I used it and I was able to get the downloadUrl.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
StorageReference imageRef = FirebaseUtil.mStorageRef.child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
    UploadTask uploadTask = imageRef.putFile(imageUri);

    uploadTask.continueWithTask(task -> {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            if (task.getException() != null)
                throw task.getException();
        }
        return imageRef.getDownloadUrl();
    }).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
               Uri downloadUri = task.getResult()

        } else {
            if (task.getException() != null)
                task.getException().printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```